# Formatted text inside TextBlock / TextBox - With binding

Tags: windows-phone-7

This might have been asked before but I'm really looking for a simple way to display a programatically formatted text inside some text container.
For decoupling purposes I would like to use a binding property, this is how I do it now:

`<TextBlock Height="219" Name="_txtBox" Text="{Binding myText}" />`

and then

`myText = "<TextBlock>\n <Run FontWeight=\"Bold\">\n" + item1 + "\n</Run>\n " + item2 + "\n</TextBlock>";`

For some unknown WP7 design reasons this does not work, I've tried with TextBox also. Is there any way that I can output some small formatted text to any kind control without over-complicating?

**I would like to keep binding in place**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you. Although I was not sure where you wanted the line breaks. You can add or remove them from the inlines collection.

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="text1" ></TextBlock>
```

Code

```
    InlineCollection inlines = text1.Inlines;
    Run r = new Run();
    r.Text = "item 1";
    r.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    inlines.Add(r);
    inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    r = new Run();
    r.Text = "item 2";
    inlines.Add(r);
```

Comment: I know the 'classic' approach, I was wondering if it was possible with data binding. My reasoning is that I want to decouple the GUI from the back end, no part should try to know what the other does.